# Glowing brackets pseudo element css

Tags: css

I'm trying to make glowing bracket for the headings, some are one line but some are two lines like on picture. Is there option to do this?  It can be straight bracket not exacty like in photo.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10%;
}

.bracket {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
.bracket:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #3ebcf5;
}
.bracket:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #3ebcf5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="bracket">NAME</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please update your answer with what you have tried.

Comment: Yes, there are loads of options to do this, you can easily do exactly this by just using CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution (in comments) was almost right. Here, I fixed some paddings: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNvyab

---

**My solution**

I used a box instead of the "[]" characters you asked for because you can't scale chars based on the container height.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
}
h1::before, h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px blue, 0 0 5px blue, 0 0 5px blue;
  background: blue;
}

h1::before {
  left: 0;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}
h1::after {
  right: 0;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>glowing in<br>the dark</h1>

<br>

<h1>like a neon light</h1>
```

Comment: cool idea, but I got this text on photo, so I need to make this bracket exactly shape

Comment: This is not so easy, because you can't scale font based on the container height. If you know beforehand how many lines the text will be, you can set the font-size accordingly.